# How to solve the bash grep error to get the average of rows

Tags: bash, awk, grep, average

I have a data set which looks like this,  I am trying to compare first two columns and if the value of first two columns are the same for two lines I am trying to get the average of other 5 columns in that rows and add it to one row. If first two columns are not the same it will output the row itself.

> 15.0  -100.0  409.27  5.7103  0.0106  0.0062  652.04
> 15.0  -99.5  409.14  5.6868  0.0109  0.0065  652.02
> 15.0  -99.0  409.23  5.4866  0.0108  0.0063  651.47
> 15.0  -98.5  409.19  5.4588  0.0107  0.0063  651.34
> 15.0  -98.5  409.17  5.3488  0.0105  0.0062  651.30
> 15.0  -98.0  409.16  5.2951  0.0104  0.0061  651.24
> 15.0  -97.5  409.17  5.2647  0.0104  0.0061  651.22
> 15.0  -97.0  409.27  5.0288  0.0098  0.0056  650.60

I am using bash and I wrote this code

```
sort -k 1 -n -k 2 -n file1 > temp
awk ‘{print $1, $2}’ temp | uniq > file2
while read line
do
    n=`grep -c "$line" temp`
    #echo $n
    grep -E "$line" temp > temp1
        awk -v n=$n '{sum+=$3} END {print sum/n}' temp1 > val1;
        awk -v n=$n '{sum+=$4} END {print sum/n}' temp1 > val2;
        awk -v n=$n '{sum+=$5} END {print sum/n}' temp1 > val3;
        awk -v n=$n '{sum+=$6} END {print sum/n}' temp1 > val4;
        awk -v n=$n '{sum+=$7} END {print sum/n}' temp1 > val5;
    
     echo $line $val1 $val2 $val3 $val4 $val5 >> Averages.dat;
done < file2
```

I keep getting this error. It looks like this line throws the error.

```
 n=`grep -c "$line" temp`
```

> grep: invalid option -- '.'
> Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
> Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Can someone please guide me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance that three or more lines have the same values in the first two columns?

Comment: Turn on `-x` to see what the offending line expands to. Maye `$line` starts with a dash? BTW, for each line in `file1`, you are creating 7 child processes. Unless the file is fairly small, you might run into performance problems.

Comment: @tshiono yes, I have around 53000 data in the text file. There is a chance there are 3 or more lines have the same values

Comment: @user1934428 I do have some negative values, like.  -15.0 -98.0 ....... . It can be that - is taken as the dash.

Comment: Then jhnc's answer looks promising. It will work even if three or more lines have the same values.

Comment: Then use a `--` to explicitly tell grep the end of the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-` is the character used to indicate an option to `grep`.

`grep` allows multiple options to be grouped after a single `-`. (See Guideline 5: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)

The GNU version of `grep` allows `-NUM` as an alias for `--context=NUM`

Your data contains at least one line whose first field is a negative number.

You can indicate to `grep` that it should treat an argument as a pattern by preceding it with `-e`.

Consider:

```
$ seq -5 5 | grep -c 3
2
$ seq -5 5 | grep -c -3
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
$ seq -5 5 | grep -c -3.0
grep: invalid option -- '.'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
$ seq -5 5 | grep -c -e -3.0
0
$
```

Note that your code is quite inefficient.

Unlesss your data is huge you can use a single `awk` call to do all the processing. Perhaps:

```
awk '
    {
        k = $1 OFS $2

        n[k]++

        s3[k] += $3
        s4[k] += $4
        s5[k] += $5
        s6[k] += $6
        s7[k] += $7
    }
    END {
        for (k in n)
            print k,
                s3[k]/n[k],
                s4[k]/n[k],
                s5[k]/n[k],
                s6[k]/n[k],
                s7[k]/n[k]
    }
' file1 >Averages.dat
```

If the input is huge, you may need to `sort` first and use a processing procedure that tracks when the key changes so that you don't need to store everything in memory. Perhaps:

```
sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 file1 | awk '
    function p() { print pk, s3/n, s4/n, s5/n, s6/n, s7/n }
    {
        k = $1 OFS $2

        if (k!=pk) {
            if (NR>1) p()
            n = s3 = s4 = s5 = s6 = s7 = 0
        }

        n++
        s3 += $3
        s4 += $4
        s5 += $5
        s6 += $6
        s7 += $7

        pk = k
    }
    END { p() }
' > Averages.dat
```

Comment: the code in the question seems to be efficiency like O( n\*log(n) + 2n + m\*(2n+5k+1) ). So O(m\*n) or maybe O(n^2) (assuming "duplicate" lines are never more than small constant-ish k (ie. n = k\*m)). I think my first code is O(n) with high memory usage and the second is O(n\*log(n)) with low memory usage.

Comment: thank you. I used your second code and it worked.